# Получиение списка установленого ПО (PowerShell) (86+x64)

Tags: powershell, реестр

Подскажите,как объединить значение двух разных веток реестра в один csv?

делаю для одной ветки:

```
  Get-ItemProperty HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | Export-Csv -path \\inW\$env:COMPUTERNAME.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
```

Хотелось бы получить в csv добавлением данные еще и из этой ветки

```
HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
```

*PowerShell 2.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь действительно о *PowerShell v2*, можно поступить, например, таким образом:

```
# данные первой ветки
$c1 = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
Where-Object {$_.DisplayName} | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
# данные второй ветки (тоже самое для другого ключа)
$c2 = ...
# объединяем и пишем в файл
$c1 + $c2[1..($c2.Length - 1)] | ConvertFrom-Csv |
Export-Csv -Path C:\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
```